# Numerical integration of a quadratic form exponential in two variables over a rectangle

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Let

$$f(x,y) = \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2}a x^2 - \frac{1}{2}c y^2 + bxy \right)$$

where $a,b\ge 0$. I want to integrate numerically:

$$\frac{\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\mathrm{d}x \int_{y_0}^{y_1}\mathrm{d}y \, f(x,y) x^n}{\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\mathrm{d}x \int_{y_0}^{y_1}\mathrm{d}y \, f(x,y)}$$

where $-\infty < x_0 < x_1 < \infty$, $-\infty < y_0 < y_1 < \infty$, and $n\in\{1,2\}$.

A naive method has problems when the peak of $f(x,y)$ is far from the rectangle of integration.

Is there a method that I can use?

Comment: Check the exponent, missing a $y^2$ term?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, thanks. Fixed.

Comment: If the peak of the Gaussian is far from the rectangle (and it doesn't have to be that far), $f(x,y)$ underflows. That's not the fault of numerical integration, nor even floating point (since approximate scale invariance is a design consideration), it's the fault of finite memory to represent floats.

Comment: The only solution is arbitrary precision.

Comment: @Moo It doesn't have to be.

Comment: @user14717 I am interested in the ratios of these integrals (see edit). The ratios do not overflow/undreflow.

Comment: @becko: Now it's interesting. Do you have some concrete numbers for $\{a, b,c, x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1\}$ that would allow a test?

Comment: @becko: How about this? Multiply top and bottom by $\exp(x_0^2+y_0^2)$ where $(x_0, y_0)$ is the peak of the Gaussian and absorb the $x_0^2+y_0^2$ into the argument of the Gaussian. That should solve the problem with underflow.

Comment: @user14717 That will not work if $x_0,y_0$ lie very far of the rectangle of truncation.

Comment: @becko: There exists some $\lambda$ such that $\lambda - \frac{1}{2}ax^2 - \frac{1}{2}by^2 +bxy$ is as close to zero as possible over the rectangle.

Comment: @user14717 But that's not enough. If the contour ellipsoids of the integrand are very tight, there will still be a region where $f(...)$ is significanly larger than outside, and this can cause numerical errors if the integration routine is not able to find this region.

Comment: @becko: Have you heard of Kahan's spy function? It sounds like you are trying to construct a function that is hiding from the quadrature routine; this is trivial to do, and there's nothing that can be done about it. (See Corless, A Graduate Intro to Numerical Methods, Theorem 10.1).

Comment: @user14717 In this case you have the ellipsoid (since you know the parameters $a,b$. So I don't think it's the same.

Comment: Presumably you can make the ellipsoid round by change of variables.

Comment: @user14717 Yes, but then the truncation rectangle changes too, into some sort of parallelogram. I'm not sure how to deal with that

Comment: @becko: Most quadrature routine require a rectangle and map that internally to $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, so my suggestion won't help unless you want to write your own quadrature routine. I suspect that the original suggestion will work just fine. Use higher precision and a tensor product tanh-sinh rule; I imagine it'll take a 100 ms.